# i want replace fourth character of each element of the string arraylist with the other character

Tags: java, arraylist, replace

```
list2.get(i).replace(list2.get(i).charAt(4), list3.get(i));
```

`list2` is the string arraylist, for example `[00110001, 11111111, 00000000, 
01001010, 00000000]`

I want to replace 4th character of each element in list2, that replacing 
character store in `list3` so it will contain `[1, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

Finally my arraylist list2 should look like `[00111001, 11110111, 00001000, 01001010, 00001000]`.

Comment: Changing `11111111` into `11110111` means that you want to flip `5th` character (the one at index 4 counting from 0). Please [edit] your question and correct this information. Also include your code attempts to solve this problem. Stack Overflow is not code factory, but problem-solving helpers.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to note that `String` is immutable. This means that you can't do this just by running any method on `list2.get(i)`. All string methods return new string values, but do not change the values of the original string.

So you have to use `list2.set( i, newValue )` to replace the previous string with a new string that you will construct.

Now, how do you construct value? You take the parts of the string that are not supposed to change, and stick the new character value between them:

Something like:

```
String oldValue = list2.get(i);
String newValue = oldValue.substring(0,3) + list3.get(i) + oldValue.substring(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like:

- Define a counter variable to be index of element in list3 starting 0.
- Iterate over each element in the list2
- Remove the string given by the iterator and convert it to charArray using toCharArray api on String
- now change the bit using 4th index in char array using list3's element pointed by counter.
- Convert char array back to String (using String(char[]) constructor) and add it to the list 2.
- increment the counter.